# I get an error : MSG529, Level 16, State 2, Line 116 Explicit conversion from data type time to int is not allowed

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Please assist me here. I get error:

```
Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 116
Explicit conversion from data type time to int is not allowed.
```

When I try to convert time column into int.

```
select convert( int , TrainDirectionCode) from [Rail_Equipment_Accident_Incident_Data 2]
```

I need to get this Extra long column to show just 1 or 2 or 3 or 4.

[image: Column]

Currently I have format: 04:00:00.0000000

Comment: That's not a MySQL error message. What RDBMS are you really using? Using square brackets around the table names usually means SQL-Server.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me. You're trying to convert a time to an integer, and that's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hour() function to extract only the hour from your time column.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this looks *a lot* more like SQL Server than MySQL...

In either case, there's no direct conversion from a Time value to an Int value.  After all, what integer does `04:00:00.0000000` represent?  4?  400?  14,400?  Why?

If this is indeed SQL Server then it sounds like what you're looking for is [the `DATEPART` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) to extract a specific "part" of the value.  Something like this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(hour, [TrainDirectionCode]) FROM [Rail_Equipment_Accident_Incident_Data 2]
```